# progress bar update in the same line of a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I love the [tqdm progress bar](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) for its simplicity. I have noted however that there are cases, where each update of the progress bar is printed in a new line of a jupyter notebook like in the following screenshot:

[image: tqdm progress update in newline]

How can I make sure that the update of a tqdm progress bar is printed in the same line in a jupyter notebook like in the following screenshot:

[image]

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tqdm` has a specific module for handling the output in jupyter notebook, [tqdm_notebook](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm_notebook/):

```py
import time
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(10)):
   time.sleep(1)
```